# Ffmpeg nvenc encoder on gpu does not compress files as much as compared to libx264

Tags: ffmpeg, nvidia, libx264, nvenc

I wanted to encode a video file which was initially encoded by a libx264 encoder on a non gpu machine with ultrafast preset and crf 23 , i typically re-encode it with preset medium and get a good compression but the process is very slow , so i am considering a gpu based solution

my current command to use ffmpeg on a nvidia turing gpu

```
ffmpeg -y -vsync passthrough -hwaccel cuda -i a.mp4 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v h264_nvenc -preset medium -tune ll -b:v 4M -bufsize 4M -maxrate 10M -qmin 0 b.mp4
```

usual command i use to do the same

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp4 -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -preset medium b.mp4
enter code here
```

How can i make this command do a better job at reducing file size , i am okay to compromise on the quality of the video for a good reduction in size

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend reading this [H.264 Video Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264)

On the surface, these variants can help you:

- Decrease your bitrate
- Add `-cq` option with suitable value 0-51 (`-cq` for h264_nvenc is pretty the same as `-crf` for libx264)
- Change `-tune` option value to `hq`
- Try two-pass encoding (if you know desired output file size), but here is very low benefit

If you struggle with available options for `h264_nvenc` you can see the whole list of them by executing following command:

```bash
ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=h264_nvenc
```

Most of them are self descriptive or similar from libx264